# More efficient raster reclassification

Tags: r, raster

I have a `raster` where the first column must be reclassified, leaving all other values as `NA`. I have written the code to do this (below) but it is very inefficient as the raster size grows much beyond this toy example.

Could someone recommend a more efficient way to re-write this code so that it can handle much larger raster files? I suspect `apply()` could be useful here but I'm unsure what direction to take this in.

```
r<-raster::raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[]<-NA

  for(i in 1:r@nrows){
    r[(r@nrows*i)-(r@ncols-1)]<-2

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a better way to do what you do

```
library(raster)
r <- raster::raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
for(i in 1:nrow(r)){
    r[i, 1] <- 2
}
```

A much better alternative

```
r <- raster::raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[,1] <- 2
```

But for larger rasters it is perhaps best do

```
r <- raster::raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
xy <- cbind(xFromCol(r, 1), yFromRow(r, 1:nrow(r)))
r <- rasterize(xy, r, field=2)
```

And probably less efficient like this

```
r <- raster::raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r <- init(r, "col")
r <- reclassify(r, rbind(c(1,1,2), c(2,Inf,NA)), right=TRUE, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Same idea, nicely concise

```
r <- subs(init(r, "col"), data.frame(from=1, to=2))
```

Comment: Saving me yet again...thanks Robert for all the possible approaches to this question!